# Filtering google maps markers with angularjs

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs

I'm using the [angular-google-maps directive](https://github.com/nlaplante/angular-google-maps) and I'm running into an issue when I try to remove markers that are bound to the controller. I've tried various versions of Angular, and have tried the master and r1-dev branch of angular-google-maps.

I don't know why, but it appears to be getting caught up in the $digest function, and this does not happen when I filter out list items. The exception that gets thrown is this:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

A demo can be seen here, my code starts at line 550 of the JavaScript. The lines above are the angular-google-maps directive.

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/4127/

Comment: Have you managed to figure out why this may be happening?

Answer (score 6):

Here is what worked for me, this is from reading some other related bugs in the angular-google-maps module issue queue.

The jist is you need to create a variable inside a watch and use that to pass to the models parameter.

Basic JS:

```
controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $filter) {

   $scope.$watch("breweryFilter", function(breweryFilter){
      $scope.filteredMarkers = $filter("filter")($scope.breweries, breweryFilter);
      if (!$scope.filteredMarkers){
        return;
      }
   });
});
```

Filter input:

```
<input name="brewery-filter" class="form-control" type="search" ng-model="breweryFilter" placeholder="filter locations" />
```

Map directive containing markers directive:

```
   <google-map
        center="map.center"
        zoom="map.zoom"
        draggable="true"
        control="map.control">

      <window
          show="breweryInfoWindow.showWindow"
          coords="breweryInfoWindow.coords"
          isIconVisibleOnClick="true"
          options="breweryInfoWindow.options"
          templateUrl="breweryInfoWindow.templateUrl"
          templateParameter="breweryInfoWindow.templateParams"
          data-ng-cloak>
        _
      </window>

      <markers
          models="filteredMarkers"
          idKey="'nid'"
          coords="'self'"
          icon="'icon'"
          doRebuildAll="true"
          fit='true'
          doCluster='true'
          control="map.markersControl"
          click="'onMarkerClicked'">
      </markers>

    </google-map>
```

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: where do you add the markers directive? `<div id="map-canvas">
    <markers
     models="filteredMarkers"
     coords="'self'"
     icon="'icon'"
     fit='true'
     doCluster='true'
     click="'onMarkerClicked'">
         </markers>
      </div>`?

Comment: Updated the answer to show the markers directive in context of the map directive